# Vue, building a select list out of array of options but pre-selecting based on async response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been trying to test out a way in vue to build a select list with a hardcoded array of options, however, if a certain async response/event comes in with an assignee attached, I am setting that as 'currentAssignee' which is my preselected option.

This *kind of* works, but it initially looks empty/invisible. If I click the seemingly non-existent select box, the options will show 'Name One', 'Name Two' and 'John Doe' which is the name from the response. But it doesn't actually satisfy the 'selected' option because it is essentially invisible to the user on page load, until it's clicked

Should I be doing something different?

```
<select class="firstLastNames linkBox" v-model="currentAssignee" @change="changeAssignee()" >
    <option :selected="true">{{currentAssigneeFirst}} {{currentAssigneeLast}}</option>
    <option v-for="assignee in assigneeOptions" >{{assignee.email}}</option>
</select>

data () {
  return {
    currentAssignee: '',
    assigneeOptions: [
          {id: 0, email: "Name one"},
          {id: 1, email: "Name two"}
    ],
  },
}

/**further down, I set currentAssignee based on async event**/
this.currentAssignee = triggerEvent[0].assignee;
```

Comment: Try to put the whole select thing into a component, and try to load it only when currentAssignee is available. Or, you can use a spinner till the data loads.

Comment: Maybe not a huge help now but you could use [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) which helps to unify this back-and-forth between UI and components for you. At least you can look in their source code to find out how they did it. Here is their [select component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a code sample together here which I think fixes your issue:
https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/bGWYggG

Take a look at what is being bound by the v-model. The "value" of a select is not the object itself, it's some value of an object.

```
    <select class="firstLastNames linkBox"  v-model="currentAssignee" @change="changeAssignee($event)" >
        <option disabled >Choose One</option>
        <option v-for="assignee in assigneeOptions" :key="assignee.id" :value="assignee.id">{{assignee.email}}</option>
    </select>
```

The important note here is the :value="assignee.id";